# Fundamental theorem of linear algebra: The rows and columns forms a basis for a matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

In my course literature, the author claims the following:

> Because the column vectors of the matrix $A^T$ is equivalent to the row vectors of $A$, the following statements **must** be equivalent
>
> 1. $A$'s column vectors forms a basis
> 2. $A$'s row vectors forms a basis

I e-mailed my tutor in class for an explanation, asking if the author had made a mistake in his book. My tutor simply reiterated what I thought the author meant.

I already understand that the row vectors of $A^T$ is equivalent to the column vectors of $A$, and the other way around. As such, I thought the author meant to say:

$A$'s column vectors forms a basis $\iff A^T$'s row vectors forms a basis

However, I don't see the author justifying such made statements with the quote I gave above.

---

I expected my tutor to have misunderstood me, and well, checking for more sources; they claim the same. How is is that the quote above is true?

Comment: the rows and the columns of a matrix span a space, one can find basis to those vector spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$'s columns form a basis, then $Aw = 0$ if and only if $w = 0$.

Now, suppose the columns of $A^T$ do **not** form a basis. Then there exists non-zero $v$ so that $A^Tv = 0$.

Then, for any $w$, we have

$$
\langle v, A w\rangle = \langle A^Tv,w\rangle = 0
$$

so that $v \in (\textrm{Im }A)^\perp$ (i.e. $\textrm{ ker }A^T \subset (\textrm{Im }A)^\perp$). But because $A$'s columns form a basis, $(\textrm{Im }A)^\perp = \{0\}$, and you have a contradiction.

(In fact, in proving the full theorem, you will show that in general, $\textrm{ ker }A^T = (\textrm{Im }A)^\perp$ etc.)

Answer (score 2):

It certainly appears that your version is the one intended.

The statement made by the author is actually true, but the "because" statement doesn't justify it at all.

Roughly: if the column vectors form a basis of $\mathbb R^n$, then there must be $n$ rows (so that the columns are in the right space), and there must be $n$ columns, because every basis of $\mathbb R^n$ has $n$ vectors. So if the column vectors form a basis, the matrix is square.

That means that the row vectors at least have some hope of forming a basis: there are $n$ of them, and each is a vector in $\mathbb R^n$. But the proof that they actually DO form a basis is not completely trivial. (@BaronVT gives a nice explanation of it, and you can see that it has little to do with the "Because" clause of your author.)

Comment: Wish I could give you both the best answer. You provided me certainty of what the author meant. Baron provided a nice way of proving the statement. Thank you.